# How to save image to internal memory of app after taking it by camera

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

I'm developing an app in which I prompt the user to take a picture with his phone and then I put this picture to my `imageView`but I want to save that picture to have it after the user restart the application.

Here is my code:

```
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    //MARK: - Take image
    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    //MARK: - Done image capture here
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    }
```

With above code I take the picture and put it in my `imageView` but I don't know how can I save it for example in `UserDefaults`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code -

**Save image -**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), forKey: "image")
```

**Retrieve image -**

```
let imageData: Data? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "image") as? Data
if let imageData = imageData
{
   var image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I test it and to retrieve the image I used this : `UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "image1") as? UIImage ?? UIImage()` but nothing happened

Comment: When I try to first launch the app it crashes because of `imageData!`, you should change it with optional `imageData ?? Data() to avoid crashes!`

Comment: Edited the answer, Thanks.